# How to generate Java file using JAX-WS wsimport and xs namespace?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate Java source files from an XML schema using JAX-WS wsimport.

My XSD files are using `xs` as the namespace instead of `xsd` and it seems that JAXB Compiler is mapping `xsd` prefixed elements by default.

I receive the following rejection:

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'https://.../1.0/XXXX.svc?xsd=xsd0', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

When looking at the file, indeed the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>` as it is `<xs:schema>` instead.

Looking at https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.3/docs/wsimport.html and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbal/index.html I could not find any parameter to use to override this expectation.

Is it at least possible to use `wsimport` with another namespace than `xsd`?

Thanks and Regards